# column.editor is ignored when using custom editor template on kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my grid column definition for my kendo grid I have

```
{ field: ProductId, title: 'Product', template: #= ProductName #', editor: MyProductSelector }
```

This works fine with the default popup editor. But when I have a custom editor template, it seems to ignore the editor field on the column. And just renders the regular input.

The input on my template looks like this:

```
    <div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="ProductIdInput">Product</label>
    </div>
    <div data-container-for="ProductIdInput" class="k-edit-field">
        <input id="ProductIdInput" name="ProductId" data-bind="value:ProductId">
    </div>
```

Is the custom editor template supposed to honour the column editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **"data-source"**, to your edit template

```
<div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="ProductIdInput">Product</label>
    </div>
    <div data-container-for="ProductIdInput" class="k-edit-field">
        <input id="ProductIdInput" name="ProductId" 
               data-bind="value:ProductId"
               data-source="MyProductSelector">
    </div>
```